# Is an "$\aleph_0$-limit" a finite limit or a small limit?

Tags: category-theory

I am sure this is a very trivial question. But I do not know anything about cardinals, and the nLab is full of them. I just want to know how to interpret a statement of the form

"$\mathcal{C}$ has $\kappa$-limits, where $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal".

If I plug in $\kappa=\aleph_0$, does the above sentence mean that $\mathcal{C}$ has finite limits or that it is complete? If it means the second, can one get the notion of finite limits from this cardinal notation?

Comment: I think finite would be $[n]$-limits for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Could you provide a page on which you've found this? Context might be helpful in providing an answer.

Comment: It is conventional to say that a category is $\kappa$-small if it has $< \kappa$ (objects and) morphisms.

Comment: Ok, so $\aleph_0$-small means finite, since anything strictly smaller than $|\mathbb{N}|$ is finite. And therefore an $\aleph_0$-limit, since it is a limit over a diagram whose domain is an $\aleph_0$-small category, recovers precisely the notion of finite limits. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is conventional to say that a category is $\kappa$-small if it has $<\kappa$ (objects and) morphisms.

So $\aleph_0$-small means finite, since anything strictly smaller than $|\Bbb N|$ is finite. 
And therefore an $\aleph_0$-limit, since it is a limit over a diagram whose domain is an $\aleph_0$-small category, recovers precisely the notion of finite limits.